# How to scale the number of variables in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, variables

Right now my page is dynamic generate content

e.g. when I press the add button , it will add a form inside the body, and each of the form contains an ajax request.

The code is like this:

```
var ajax;

ajax = $.ajax.....
```

The problem is , it only limit the variable to one , I would like to know is there any way that can scale the number of variable

For example: when two form are added , then there will be two ajax variable, and how to keep track on them?

Thanks for helping.

**Update: case explanation**

The reason of doing this is because I would like to cancel the ajax submit, so the case is :

```
var ajax_req;

$("form").submit(function(){
     ajax_req = $.ajax...
});

$("cancel").click(function(){
    ajax_req.cancel();
});
```

But for dynamic generate form I need to keep track of all ajax_req variable and know which form I am going to cancel.

Comment: You'll need a data structure, very basic JS. See [Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) and [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: Or, there is rarely a need to persistently store the promise that `$.ajax()` returns.  If you show us the rest of the actual context (what you are actually trying to do), we can help you solve your issue much more thoroughly.

Comment: sure, updated question

Comment: Arrays are your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution is converting the form submit to ajax request.

it's easy, just 3 steps:

1. prevent the original form submit.
2. get the form variables. i'd like to use `.serialize()`.
3. make an ajax.

advanced, you can set some parameter in the form tag, like `method="post"`, or some other `"data-"` attributes. and you can read these parameters before requesting.

hope this helps :D

Comment: Thanks , using an array of ajax obj fixed the problem

Comment: it's not the best way i think. you may try the .data()